# Report Viewer doesn't show data but the table only

Tags: c#, reportviewer, reportviewer2008

Report Viewer Control (WinForm) doesn't show data but the table only.

But if I execute RDL file with ReportViewer 2.0 it shows all data well.

It uses User DSN ODBC reference.

[image]

```
private void reportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
  reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "dlm1.rdl";
  var rds = new ReportDataSource();
  rds.Name = "DataSet1";
  rds.Value = "DataSource1";
  reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
  reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
}
```

Part of RDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition">
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="DataSource1">
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>ODBC</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>Dsn=DLM User</ConnectString>
        <IntegratedSecurity>true</IntegratedSecurity>
      </ConnectionProperties>
      <rd:DataSourceID>a900984d-8acf-416a-8130-8cc5086e1c03</rd:DataSourceID>
      <rd:SecurityType>Windows</rd:SecurityType>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="id">
          <DataField>id</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="expectedStartTime">
          <DataField>expected
```

Any clue?

Comment: can you share the RDL part of the tablix ?

Comment: @JacobSiemaszko Hey! :) Thanks for the input! I am not sure if it will help. RDl file is generated automatically and show data with MS Report Builder 2.0 so it is correct internally. Something wrong with C# code or ReportViewer Control. But one thing I know that C# code opens RDL file. It should activate DSN data source somehow... I am not sure if it can do this....